# How to Calculate the Percentage of Manufacturers with Sales Above Global Average Sales by Category in Tableau using Super Store Dataset

Tags: tableau-desktop

This Question is related to **Tableau Sample Super Store Dataset**:

Q. For each **Category**, calculate the percentage of **manufacturer** that have sales above the global average sales.

Eg.
global average sales: 228.23

For category **furniture**, 47 **manufacturers** are there out of which 40 **manufacturers'** sales is above the global average sales.

Required outcome:

| Category | %age of manufacturer above global average sales |
| --- | --- |
| Furniture | 85.11% |

Help me in solving this

Not able to figure out how to solve this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.